# Backbone router navigate to .../#/<route> without triggering router event. How to?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Don't know how to force backbone correctly navigate to routes like this:

> page/#/channel/name

instead of

> page#channel/name

or

> page#/channel/name

My router works with one main model and observes its states, so the router should be able to change URL without triggering its events in this case.

I tried to do like this:

```
router.navigate("#/channel/" + encodeURIComponent(appState.data.channelName), { trigger: false });
```

but in this case "trigger: false" didn't work, so I got undesirable call of router event.

Backbone.history root is set to "/", and I'm currently not using pushState.

See code example below:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "index",            
        "index": "index",
        "channel/:channelName": "changeChannel"
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        var router = this;

        if (options.model) {
            router.model = options.model;
        } else {
            //TODO: throw error
            return;
        }

        //update url in cases of model channelSelection changes
        router.model.on("stateChangeAccepted", function (appState) {
            switch (appState.mode) {
                case "channel":
                    router.navigate("/channel/" 
                        + encodeURIComponent(appState.data.channelName), { trigger: false });
                    break;                    
            }
        });
    },

    index: function () {
        var router = this;

        router.model.trigger("stateChangeRequest", {
            mode: "channel",
            data: {
                channelIndex: 0
            }
        });

    },

    changeChannel: function (channelName) {
        var router = this;

        router.model.trigger("stateChangeRequest", {
            mode: "channel",
            data: {
                channelName: decodeURIComponent(channelName)
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Avoid using leading slashes, so don't use /page#/channel/ but use /page#channel. It is documented in the Backbone documentation that it is better to do so. This might solve your problem

Comment: It works fine without slashes, I know. I just wanted to get page/#/channel URLs, similar to Twitter

Answer (score 0):

Your `router.navigate` call does not match the route you defined:

```
routes: {
  "": "index",            
  "index": "index",
  "channel/:channelName": "changeChannel"
},
```

This means that the URL for a channel should be `http://host.com/#channel/someChannel`. However, your router.navigate calls are either `router.navigate('#/channel...)` or `router.navigate('/channel...)`. It should be:

```
router.navigate("channel/" + encodeURIComponent(appState.data.channelName), { trigger: false });
```

If, however, you want to use routes like `http://host.com/#/channel/someChannel`, then your route should be:

```
routes: {
  "": "index",            
  "index": "index",
  "/channel/:channelName": "changeChannel"
},
```

and your navigate call should be:

```
router.navigate("/channel/" + encodeURIComponent(appState.data.channelName), { trigger: false });
```

Comment: In this case I get URLs like page/#channel/someChannel, not page/#/channel/someChannel. Furthermore, now such generated routes don't call router actions at all (when refreshing page)

Comment: Can you show what you have now that's preventing route functions from triggering? In Backbone.js, URLs take the form `host+"#"+route`. If your route is `"/channel/:channelName"`, then a URL of `http://host.com/#/channel/someChannel` SHOULD work, although something else might be happening

Comment: I made everything as described in your post:
1. set route in routes as "/channel/:channelName": "changeChannel"
2. navigate to "/channel/..."
It doesn't call appropriate router event... When I delete leading slashes from the both points, it works fine.

Comment: Interesting. In that case, it looks like Vincent Briglia was right; leading slashes in routes may just not work. The docs say to avoid using them: http://backbonejs.org/#Router-extend